# Hide empty UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, admob

I am using AdMob to display ads in my `UITableView`. It is working fine but i am getting empty cells in my table when the ad changes cell.

How can i hide the old and empty cell? See picture for the problem

[image]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int row = [indexPath row];
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    if(kAdFrequency - 1 == row%kAdFrequency){
        CellIdentifier = @"AdCell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        [cell addSubview:_banner];
        return cell;
    }else{
        row = row - floor((float)row/kAdFrequency);

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        NGNationEventDay* day = [_events objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        NGNationEvent* event = [day.events objectAtIndex:row];

        cell.textLabel.text = event.name;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = event.category;

        return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the ad changing place?  Could you post some code which may help solve the problem?

Comment: I believe the ad is changing cell when [cell addSubView:_banner] is called. I have added the code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in general the best way of doing this would be just to make sure that your ads are showing up at a frequency where there are never two ad cells on screen at once (you can probably just modify kAdFrequency to make this the case).